# Nearest point from the origin

Tags: real-analysis

Find the point on the surface $x^2+2y^2-z^2-1$ that is nearest to the origin.

I know we have to use Lagrange's method of multipliers here. But I am having trouble finding a specific point in this case.

Comment: You want $x^2+2y^2-z^2-1=0$ to define a surface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to minimise the function 
$$
\left\|\cdot\right\|:(x,y,z)\mapsto\left\|(x,y,z)\right\|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}
$$
subject to the constraint
$$
x^2+2y^2-z^2-1=0.
$$

By the method of Lagrange multipliers this task amounts to minimizing the function
$$
(x,y,z,\lambda)\mapsto\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}-\lambda(x^2+2y^2-z^2-1).
$$
Setting the four partial derivatives equal to zero results in a system of four equations with four unknowns, which has four real solutions $(x,y,z,\lambda)$. These are
$$
\left\{(-1,0,0,1/2),(1,0,0,1/2),(0,-1/\sqrt{2},0,1/(2\sqrt{2})),(0,1/\sqrt{2},0,1/(2\sqrt{2}))\right\}.
$$

The points on the surface nearest to the origin are thus $(0,\pm1/\sqrt{2},0)$.

You may want to check that the critical points so computed are indeed local minima rather than, say, maxima.

Comment: would be easier minimizing $||\cdot||^2$ rather than $||\cdot||$

Comment: No, I don't think squaring would be easier than this.

Comment: sorry to butt in, but what is this symbol ∥⋅∥ should be read as? thank u. @yohBS

Comment: @alethiologist norm http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Notation

Answer (score 2):

You want to minimize $x^2+y^2+z^2$ assuming $z^2=x^2+2y^2+1$. So you have $x^2+y^2+z^2=2x^2+3y^2+1$. It is obvious that the minimal value of $2x^2+3y^2+1$ is attained for $x=y=0$.